# Android - The right way to send many requests

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm working on a project where quick responsivness is very important, and basicly what it does is getting current location of the user, gets a bunch (can be few hundrends at most) of locally stored LatLng objects and requests the google web api for directions.

My question is - What would be the 1) right way to do it and 2) not take ages to finish (assuming a decent net connection)

Right now I took the path of - create a thread for each of the requests and update some data structure, when all threads finish , continue evaluation

this is basicly my code:

```
private class RetrieveTracks extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Data> {

    private Data data;

    @Override
    protected Data doInBackground(Void... params) {
        data = new Data(); 
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for (LatLng lat : lats) { //lats is some collection with the LatLng objects I got
                Thread thread = new Thread(new DirectionsFinder(lat, data, currentLocation)); 
                threads.add(thread);
                thread.start();
        }
        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Data data) {
        //update map with Data
    }
}

public class DirectionsFinder implements Runnable {

  private LatLng lat;
  private Data data;
  private LatLng curLoc;


  public DirectionsFinder(Latlng lat, Data data, LatLng curLoc) {
    this.lat = lat;
    this.data = data;
    this.curLoc = curLoc;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
        //send GET request to google web api and get the directions
        synchronized (data) {
            //update data
        }
    }
  }
```

also a side question I got - in some occasions I might get in the mid of the execution enough data such that I no longer need to get information, is there a way to 'break' out of the resst of the running threads?

At first I tried to use Callable and FutureTask for what I'm trying to do but coulnd't find a convinient way to to the joining phase which is very important so I gave up on it

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you ideally want the direction response from Google on all latlongs before you continue after a track retrieval ? Your scenario sounds typical for say a courier who has 10 packets to deliver around town and wants to determine the most effective driving plan for delivering them all. Then trying to get the driving directions for all of the destinations individually helps in the calculation. Each call to Google results in eventually receiving the direction for one trip and several requests add up in total response time. You may need to determine some time limit on how long to wait for each response. I am not sure if you are prepared to abandon or retry a slow responding request. If you are in a mobile situation with the device running the app you might not be able to assure a decent response time for all of the requests.  This is not a conclusive answer but your response can help the community come up with more precise advice.

Comment: I'm actually looking for the nearest (in terms of directions route length) latlong. timelimit is something I probably will actually need to add but since I rather wait few more seconds and get a location which is closer then I think we can safely assume for the purpose of the question that no time limit exists